# gyp_main.py: error: no such option: --no-parallel

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-gyp

running `npm install` to install development dependencies of [sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) project, I get this `node-gyp configure error`:

```
> fs-ext@0.4.5 install /home/remi/_projects/gitlab/SWAP/sirap-private-npm/node_modules/fs-ext
> node-gyp configure build

Usage: gyp_main.py [options ...] [build_file ...]

gyp_main.py: error: no such option: --no-parallel
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-29-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/remi/_projects/gitlab/SWAP/sirap-private-npm/node_modules/fs-ext
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Tried

```
npm cache clean
```

and

```
npm install
```

some times but no effect. Always throwing this error. `node-gyp` can't build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `gyp` depends on `python 2.6` and don't support  `python 2.7` yet.

You must downgrade python version thanks to [fkrull's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.6 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 10
```

If you want to change this choice later

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

This CLI interface will ask you wich version is used automatically, and wich ones must be used manually.

Then, in your project folder :

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to upgrade the gyp version used internally by npm:

`sudo npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp@latest`

See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm%27s-bundled-node-gyp